# undefined method `find_or_initialize' for a Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I've migrated to Rails 4 from Rails 3.2. I had this:

```
  MyModel.find_or_initialize_by_field1("fdsfdsfds")
```

Now I have this

```
  MyModel.where(field1: "fdsfdsfds").find_or_initialize
```

which now causes an exception in the tests:

```
   undefined method `find_or_initialize' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

But in the guide it says nothing about what else should be there. How to fix it?

Comment: Was this result of automated upgrade tool?

Answer (score 2):

That's happening because when the returned result is an empty array you can't call the find_or_initalize method on it.  Try:

```
   MyModel.where(field1: 'asdfasdfasdf').first_or_initialize
```

Answer (score 2):

`MyModel.where(field1: "fdsfdsfds")` return a collection which behaves like an array in many respects.  If you want to call `.find_or_initialize_by`, pass in a hash:

```
MyModel.find_or_initialize_by(field1: "fdsfdsfds")
```

Many of the old `.something_by_attr(x)`methods can be expressed just as cleanly with `.something_by(attr: x)`

Answer (score 1):

Although they look similar, the two methods you mention, `find_or_initialize_by_X` and `find_or_initialize`, are very different.

The `find_or_initialize_by_`-type methods are finders defined on subclasses of `ActiveRecord::Base`, i.e. activerecord models. They return a single record, or a new instance if none matches the query condition.

The second `find_or_initialze` method is being called not on a model class (`MyModel`) but (as the error implies) on `ActiveRecord::Relation`. That's because when you call `where` the result you get is a relation, not an array or a single record.

Although arrays and relations look similar, Rails will avoid converting a relation into an array until it has no other choice, since doing so implies actually executing SQL and creating objects, which is performance heavy and only necessary when you need to actually inspect the results.

The problem with your second call to `find_or_initialize` is that `ActiveRecord::Relation` has no `find_or_initialize` method; it has a `first_or_initialize` method. (It has nothing to do with the fact that the result set is empty in the case above.) `first_or_initialize` fetches the first result in the relation or initializes a new model if the result was empty.

So the short answer is you should just call: `MyModel.where(field1: 'foo').first_or_initialize`.

As mentioned in the other answers, there are other ways however to do the same thing without using relations, e.g.:

```
MyMode.find_or_initialize_by(field1: "foo")
```

This is closer to `find_or_initialize_by_X` that you used in Rails 3.2, and actually all else being equal, you should use `find_by` over the `where(...).first` pattern for performance reasons: `where(...).first` will result in SQL ordered by primary key, which will be slower than the `SELECT` generated by `find_by`.